# Problem display in IE 7 & IE 6 - simplemodal-1.3.4 and Jquery 1.4.2

Tags: jquery-plugins, simplemodal

I have a link, after click this link, a modal was displayed. I used ModalDialog with code:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    //linkTTT is link id
        $("a#linkTTT").click(function() {
        //content is id of div that contains content
            $("#content").modal({ onOpen: function(dialog) {
                dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function() {
                    dialog.data.hide();
                    dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function() {
                        dialog.data.slideDown('slow');
                    });
                });
            }

            });


         }); //end a click
    });
```

Content're contained in a , it includes two tables that containt text and some images.

This application run well in Firefox 3+, Chrome and IE8.

Images here: [http://bian.vn/normal.png]

I'm having problem with IE 6 and IE 7. 
In IE 6:

Images here: [http://bian.vn/IE6.png]

In IE 7, content's cleaned after is loaded...

Images here: [http://bian.vn/IE7.png]

You can see screencast at [link text](http://screenr.com/MvM)

Let me know your answer about this problem 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for my problem :)

In `<div>` tag that have `id="content"`, I included two tables. After I remove table. It's resolved!

Thanks for viewing :)